# Creating random multigraph with parallel edges but no self loops with given node degree

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a given graph with certain node degree sequence [23,100,1225,40....n]. My aim is to randomise graph generation based on node degree of my graph but without self-loops. Parallel edges are allowed. My original graph also has parallel edges but no self-loops.
Tried networkxx package configuration_model. But it returns a multigraph with self-loops, on removing them I do not maintain node degree. Is there any algorithms to achieve this?
I also tried randomly picking 2 nodes and making an edge between them. But I always end with a single vertex (with unfilled node degree) (don't want self loops) and unassigned edges remaining.

Below code I get 2 random node ids from my original graph and assign them a link. While doing this I keep checking if the node degree isnt reached capacity. But as expected I always end up with a single node remaining and lot of unassigned links.

```
success_dict = defaultdict(list)  
popped_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for pfxpair in pfxlinks:
    start_put = False    
    end_put = False
  
    
    while True:
        grid_start_id, grid_end_id = (np.random.choice(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys()),size = 2, replace = False)) # get 2 random node ids
        grid_start_id = int(grid_start_id)
        grid_end_id = int(grid_end_id)
        
        if start_put == False:
            
            start_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_start_id)    # if node id exists in my dict and node degree hasnt reached capacity
            
            start_process_condition = (not start_value) or ( (start_value) and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]) )
            if start_process_condition:
                grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].add(pfxpair)
                start_put = True
            
                if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]: # node degree for node full, remove from dict
                    
                    try:
                        #print('deleted key: ',grid_start_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id])
                        popped_dict[grid_start_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) }

                        grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_start_id)
                    
                    except:
                        print('already popped')
        else:
            print('check')
          
                
       
                        
        if end_put == False: 
            
                                
            end_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_end_id)
            if (not end_value) or (end_value and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])):
                grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].add(pfxpair)
                end_put = True
                
                if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id]:
                    try:
                        #print('deleted key: ',grid_end_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])
                        popped_dict[grid_end_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) }

                        grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_end_id)

                    except:
                        print('already popped')
        else:
            print('check')
            
            
        
        if (start_put == False and end_put == True):      # only end while when both nodes have been assigned a link
            grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].discard(pfxpair)
            end_put = False
        if (start_put == True and end_put == False):
            grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].discard(pfxpair)
            start_put = False

            
            
        
                
        if start_put == True and end_put == True:
            success_dict[pfxpair].append((grid_start_id,grid_end_id))

            break
```

Comment: sorry - it's not clear to me if you want no multiple edges or if you want to include them.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: If you're okay with some pseudo-randomness, could you 1) randomly generate the graph that has self-loops, 2) remove the self loops, 3) add back edges one at a time between the two nodes have that have the greatest difference in degree from the desired values?  This may get around the problem of ending up with one single node that has the incorrect degree.

Comment: @Joel I edited my question to be clear. I am ok with multiple edges between 2 nodes but no self-loops.

Comment: How random does it have to be?  Truly uniform at random?  Or just pretty close to random?  And how big are the networks?

Comment: I am trying to make 1000 random graphs to test my hypothesis, so I guess they have to be  as  random as possible without bias. That is the reason I use np.random.choice() to select 2 nodes at random. My current graph has 66 nodes and 1496 edges, but this can become very big too.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard.  Depending on how dense your network is, the best option may be to

1. generate the network.
2. check if it has desired properties
3. if not, repeat until it does.

It may be a good idea to track how many self edges there are each time just to make sure that you aren't setting yourself up for an infinite loop. It will generally be Poisson distributed.  If it's centered too far from 0 it can run for a very long time.

Alternately, here is an approach for generating random simple graphs with given degree distribution: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0010012.  I've never read the paper myself, but I know it's a hard problem.  I was surprised they were able to find it.

Comment: Thanks but my code ensures no self loops are created. Not sure if I should just keep running until I find an isomorphic graph? The paper is for simple graphs as you say. I need a multigraph with multiple edges but no self loops.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "isomorphic" in this context?

Comment: When I want a random graph with same number of nodes and same node degree as my original graph. I think both can be called as isomorphic. According to definition of isomorphism: ''A graph can exist in different forms having the same number of vertices, edges, and also the same edge connectivity. Such graphs are called isomorphic graphs"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think that what you tried (picking up 2 random nodes) might actually work. You just have to be sure you won't end up with a single node in the end. For that, you can just test if there is a node that has a degree that is half of the total degrees remaining. That means that the rest of the edges will be connected to this node.

Note that if the sum of the degrees is odd, the problem won't have a solution. Same problem if a node has a degree that is more than half of the sum of the degrees.

Comment: Thanks, I posted my code attempt. It is interesting what you say to check if a node has a degree that is equal to half of total degrees remaining. Where should I check for this? And what to do when I find this? Total nodes : 66, total links to assign: 2992, node with max degree which always ends up alone has degree: 1225

Comment: @skynaive You should check this before you pick 2 random nodes, and if that is the case that means that all the remaining edges are connected to this node

Comment: Could you suggest a way I can ensure an isomorphic graph is generated?